# Get the response from server in JSON format without using database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, jquery

I am new to server side programming, I have a `form` and action required is, when user fill the name, address and pin code, submit the from then page should be load (like native from submit) and new data should be display (data is available in JSON file).

I have JSON files on the server. Is it possible to get the response from server in JSON format without using database??

HTML:---

```
<form action="https://domain.com/jsonfilelocation/json.json">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="address" />
    <input type="text" name="pincode" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />        
</form>
```

JSON:--- json.json located in `https://domain.com/jsonfilelocation/json.json`

```
{
    "name": "kk",
    "address": "XYZ, New Delhi",
    "pincode": "1000001"
}
```

Comment: Why do I think your json file does nothing, but having static json formatted array

Comment: @RoyalBg: it it just an example to explain, I have all the data available in JSON format!

Comment: You can request it via ajax, to show the response in the current page, otherwise you will send the user to open the .json file :) I'd rather request the file in another .php file and echo the response, because sending request to .json file is not familiar to me

Comment: don't you want to *store* the user's entry somewhere? If not, why do you want to send it to the server? Maybe take a step back and describe the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your JSON string in a local variable server side and have it returned as the result of a client side AJAX call without having to access a database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is [JQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), if you don't mind using JQuery library, which I would heavily recommend.

It basically uses AJAX for requesting the json file and parses it:

```
$.getJSON('https://domain.com/jsonfilelocation/json.json', function(data) {
    // 'data' is your object containing the parsed JSON data
    var new_name = data.name
    var new_address = data.address
    var new_pincode = data.pincode
    // ...
```

Read the doc link I give you, it's very well written.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

//Variables
$ext    = '.json';
$me     = isset($_SESSION['me']) ? $_SESSION['me'] : $_SESSION['me'] = rand();
$file   = $me . $ext;

//If we have a post handle our data, write to a json file.
if ($_POST) {
    //Don't need the submit key in our data.
    unset($_POST['submit']);

    //Write to the file.
    $str    = json_encode($_POST);
    $fp     = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fputs($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}

//Check if there is a file with our session name.
if (file_exists($file)) {
    //Get the file content and json decode it.
    $json   = file_get_contents($file);
    $values = json_decode($json);
}
?>
<!-- Form with pre-populated values, if they are set -->
<form action=""method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php print isset($values->name) ? $values->name : ''; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php print isset($values->address) ? $values->address : ''; ?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="pincode" value="<?php print isset($values->pincode) ? $values->pincode : ''; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Up to you to make it save tough. But i think that should give you a good idea of the possibilities and how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

just request the page `https://domain.com/jsonfilelocation/json.json` when doing your request.